# How to split string while keeping \n

Tags: python, list

I want to write the first letter of every item while linebreak stays the same but when I turn the list to string it's written in one line. Like this `"I w t w f l o e I w l s s"` but I want output to look like this `"I w t \n w t f l \n o e i \n w l \n s s"`.

```
r = '''I want to
write the first letter 
of every item
while linebreak
stay same'''

list_of_words = r.split()
m = [x[0] for x in list_of_words]
string = ' '.join([str(item) for item in m])
print(string)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing is you are splitting all the lines in a single go, so you are losing the information of each line. You need to create list of list to preserve the line information.

When you provide `no argument` `means split according to any whitespace`, that means both `' ' and '\n'`.

```py
r = '''I want to
write the first letter 
of every item
while linebreak
stay same'''

list_of_words = [i.split() for i in r.split('\n')]
m = [[y[0] for y in x] for x in list_of_words]
string = '\n'.join([' '.join(x) for x in m])
print(string)
```

```
I w t
w t f l
o e i
w l
s s
```

Comment: Note that you can make use of generators in this answer for intermediate values rather than first creating a list: `string = '\n'.join([' '.join(x) for x in m])` should be replaced with just `string = '\n'.join(' '.join(x) for x in m)`. You can also make `m` and `list_of_words` generators if they won't be needed anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Via regexp

```
r = '''I want to
write the first letter 
of every item
while linebreak
stay same'''

import re

string = re.sub(r"(.)\S+(\s)", r"\1\2", r + " ")[:-1]

print(string)
```

Output:

```
I t
w t f l 
o e i
w l
s s
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is - *Get the first letter from each word
of the list and then joining them.* You are not keeping track of the `\n` in the string.

You could do this instead.

```
list_of_words = r.split('\n')
m = [[x[0] for x in y.split()] for y in list_of_words]
for i in m:
    string = ' '.join(i)
    print(string)
```

```
Output

I w t
w t f l
o e i
w l
s s
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution by using while loop

```
r = '''I want to
write the first letter 
of every item
while linebreak
stay same'''


total_lines = len(r.splitlines())
line_no = 0
while line_no < total_lines:
    words_line = r.splitlines()[line_no]
    list_of_words = words_line.split()
    m = [x[0] for x in list_of_words]
    print(' '.join([str(item) for item in m]))
    line_no = line_no + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Since many valid methods were already provided, here's a nice and comprehensive way of doing the same task without the use of `str.split()`, which creates unnecessary list intermediates in memory (not that it represents any problem in this case though).

This method takes advantage of **`str.isspace()`** to deliver the whole set of instructions in one line:

```
string = "".join([string[i] for i in range(len(string)) if string[i].isspace() or string[i-1].isspace() or i == 0])
```